# How to make this expression like $x^2y+y^2z+xz^2-yz^2-x^2z-xy^2=(x-y)(x-z)(y-z)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

$$x^2y+y^2z+xz^2-yz^2-x^2z-xy^2=(x-y)(x-z)(y-z)$$

I would like to know if there is any method by which you can have like this result.

Comment: Your question is not clear. What do you mean by "like this result"?

Comment: It is trivial: simply expand the second member.

Answer (score 0):

It is zero for x=y, x=z, and y=z,
so x-y, x-z, and y-z are factors.

Since the product of those three has terms of degree 3 
like the expression,
the two are equal.

In general, in a multi-parameter expression,
it is often useful to look for special values
of the parameters that make the
expression zero or
other distinguished values.

Answer (score 0):

If you instead of x or y or z write any other letter of those 3 you'll get 0, so the first polynomial can be divided by any of (x-y),(y-z),(x-z). You just have to find the parameter $a$ which multiplies them all to get your polynomial, it's -1

Answer (score 0):

A ‘natural’ and elementary way to factor this expression, which is derived from $x^2y-xy^2$ by a circular permutation, is to break this symmetry between all variables.

Let's illustrate this by rewriting $z-x=(z-y)-(x-y)$. We obtain
\begin{align*}
x^2y+y^2z+xz^2&-yz^2-x^2z-xy^2=xy(x-y)+yz(y-z)+zx(z-x)\\
&=xy(x-y)+yz(y-z)+zx(z-y)-zx(x-y)\\
&=(xy-zx)(x-y)+(yz-zx)(z-y)\\&=x(y-z)(x-y)+z(y-x)(z-y)\\
&=(x-y)(y-z)[x-z]=\color{red}{-(x-y)(y-z)(z-x)}.
\end{align*}